# zip file and download from client or server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I need to pull a set of arrays, they have values like 'http://example.com/1.png' and I have to zip and download them when a user click 'download' on the cilent side.

For that part should I do it on server or client side? I found few npm that can do the job but I doubt it should be at the server side, since I can pass my data from db to cilent.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of zipping files on a frontend(using [jszip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip) for example) client probably will download images faster because most modern browsers can have 6 downloads at the same time, but on another hand, it has it's own [limitations and issues](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/limitations.html).

So I would suggest using server-side compression because it's more stable and flexible(using [node-zip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-zip) for example).

Comment: zip at the back, push to the front, just use `http` download method?

Comment: You can use HTTP GET with `'Content-Type' = 'application/zip'` or just redirect to the endpoint with an archive.